# How to reauthenticate a user using nativescript and firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, nativescript

I'm developing an app using nativescript and firebase.
On the firebase.init method i use

#### persist : true

When i close the app and reopen it the init method gets the current user on the

#### onAuthStateChanged callback

But still not understand the whole process.
My question is :

#### Is the init method anought for user reauthentication ??

Or should i do something more??

Comment: After the app starts with the help of `onAuthStateChanged `you will see if the user is logged-in or not. Based on that information you should provide your business logic for handling unauthorized users (e.g. login screen or some limited free access or else)

Comment: Thanks but when i remove the user from the console, the onAuthStateChanged still return the user and loggedIn = true !
My question is how to deal with it ?

Answer (score 1):

save the email and password on local storage and when the app startup call in the ngoninit the login function with the email and password from local storage
if the data exist the login process will finish successfully if not used will move to the login page.

Comment: Never keep your password locally in localStorage that sounds like a security threat.